# 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true - flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

my music player is playing the first file totally fine, but when switching to the next song, it shows this error:

> 'package:flutter/src/material/slider.dart': Failed assertion: line 132 pos 15: 'value >= min && value <= max': is not true.

the values I'm sending to slider are not going to be negative or even null,
I'm sending values this way:

```
          Slider(
                  value: _duration != null
                      ? _duration > defdur
                          ? _position?.inMilliseconds?.toDouble() ?? 0.0
                          : 0.0
                      : 0.0,
                  onChanged: (double value) {
                    return audioPlayer.seek((value / 1000).roundToDouble());
                  },
                  min: 0.0,
                  max: _duration != null
                      ? _duration > defdur
                          ? _duration.inMilliseconds.toDouble()
                          : 0.0
                      : 0.0),
```

the defdur is default duration i made like this:

```
var defdur = Duration(milliseconds: 0);
```

so basically i have two inline if statements, for checking if value is null or not bigger than 1 milliseconds, return 0
and still problem occurs!

Comment: Just a hunch, maybe the slider position is not reset when you change the song and the new song is shorter than the old one...?

Comment: that was the case, thank you so much, i really appreciate that

Answer (score 5):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4Blf.png)

Just increase 1 to the max parameter, Because, for example, some audio clips have their real time 4:00:01, and therefore this number is already greater than 4:00:00

Comment: Try copy pasting the code here and use the **code format** instead of uploading a picture of your code

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
return audioPlayer.seek((value / 1000).roundToDouble().round());
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the **minimum Max value of Flutter Sliders is 20,** **keep the max value 20 or greater than 20**, **simply add a condition if value < 20 ? 20 : value**

```
Slider(
    min: 0,
    max: value.toInt() < 20 ? 20 : value,
    value: _value,
    onChanged: (value) {}
)
```

Answer (score -2):

Just Move the `min` and `max` properties in between the `value` property and the `onChanged` function will looks like the following :

```
value : yourValue,
min:0.0,
max: 1.0,
onChanged: (double NewValue){
 //YOUR CODE
}
```